# Enter\Exit the PowerShell mode in the Package Manager Console window

Tags: nuget, package-managers

I think I accidentally entered the PowerShell mode so currently my console says:
PS> c:\dev\

I wonder how do you exit from PS> mode to get back to PM mode?
I want the console window to show PM> so I can install packages

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Try restarting VS. Unless you explicitly typed something in

Comment: @dfowler I had the same issue, the answer fixed it for me. What causes this?

Comment: There's a race condition we found that causes this to happen at times. I believe we're working on a possible fix for it.

Comment: @dfowler Is there a way to restart nuget from the console if that happens?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. I tried to restart VS with no effect, the "Package Manager Console" started in PowerShell again.

But this worked:

- close the "Package Manager Console"
- restart VS
- open Package Manager Console"