# Visual Studio 2015 - Stopping Process In Package Manager Console

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, gulp

I am executing a "gulp serve" command which spins up a server using node.js. I am trying to stop the process so I can use the console again. However, pressing the red STOP button in the console has no effect. The only way I seem to be able to stop the process is if I go to the Task Manager and stop "Node.js" itself as a process, to which the console then says

"The pipeline has been stopped"

And allows me to use the package manager console again.

Any ideas on how to allow me to easily stop either node or allow the stop button to actually work? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9565275/7411070 is the only working solution